# How to set the address when create a customer on Netsuite use REST Web

Tags: php, netsuite

Currently i'm learning Nesuite using REST Web. i want to create a customer but i struggle to set an address. if i not set the address, it can create. but when i tried to set the addresss, it display error. I read from this doc [Add Customer](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/APIs/REST_API_Browser/record/v1/2022.1/index.html#tag-customer)

I'm using Postman to test the endpoint. and here is my body json

```
{
    "companyName": "New York {{$timestamp}}",
    "email": "newyork@ny.com",
    "subsidiary" : 9,
    "phone" : "021-021-2222",
    "entitystatus" : 13,
    "addressBook": {
        "items" : [
                    {
                        "addressBookAddress": {
                            "addr1": "123 Street",
                            "addrPhone": "12312312",
                            "addrText" : "addrText",
                            "addressee" : "addressee",
                            "city" : "New York",
                            "country" : {
                                "id" : [ "US"],
                                "refName" : "United State"
                            },
                            "state" : "NY",
                            "zip" : "1222"
                        } ,
                        "addressBookAddress_text" : "address text",
                        "label" : "label"
                    }
                    
                ]
    }
    
}
```

but display error

> {
> "type": "https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1",
> "title": "Bad Request",
> "status": 400,
> "o:errorDetails": [
> {
> "detail": "Invalid content in the request body.",
> "o:errorCode": "INVALID_CONTENT"
> }
> ]
> }

i not sure how to fix this. i've been search for other documentation but still not work. please help

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem some months ago and I solved it after developing the function below. I have adapted it to your JSON. Even this function is ready to define the address as the shipping address, billing address or both.

```
    /**
     * Receives the address object coming in the field addressBookAddress of your JSON and set it for the customer indicated by her ID.
     * @param int customerId Internal ID of the customer in Netsuite.
     * @param boolean shipping Whether you want or don't want to set this address as the shipping address.
     * @param boolean billing Whether you want or don't want to set this address as the billing address.
     */
    function addAddress(customerId, address, shipping, billing) {
        try {
            // Looking up the country
            let country = address.country;
            let state = address.state;

            /**
             * Load the record to gain access to the Address sublist
             */
            let customer = record.load({
                type: record.Type.CUSTOMER,
                id: this.customerId,
                isDynamic: false
            });

            customer.insertLine({
                sublistId: 'addressbook',
                line: 0
            });
            let line = 0;

            /**
             * Modify those fields present in the Address sublist lines
             */
            customer.setSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'addressbook',
                fieldId: 'defaultbilling',
                value: billing, // this is true or false
                line: line
            });

            customer.setSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'addressbook',
                fieldId: 'defaultshipping',
                value: shipping, // this is true or false
                line: line
            });

            customer.setSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'addressbook',
                fieldId: 'isresidential',
                value: true,
                line: line
            });

            /**
             * Load the sublist record, which holds all the actual address fields
             */
            let subrec2 = customer.getSublistSubrecord({
                sublistId: 'addressbook',
                fieldId: 'addressbookaddress',
                line: line
            });

            /**
             * Modify all subrecord fields
             */
            subrec2.setValue({
                fieldId: 'country',
                value: country
            });

            subrec2.setValue({
                fieldId: 'attention',
                value: 'The attention value you want to set'
            })

            subrec2.setValue({
                fieldId: 'addressee',
                value: address.addressee
            })

            subrec2.setValue({
                fieldId: 'addr1',
                value: address.addr1
            });

            subrec2.setValue({
                fieldId: 'addr2',
                value: address.addr2 // If necessary
            });

            subrec2.setValue({
                fieldId: 'addr3',
                value: address.addr3 // If necessary
            })

            subrec2.setValue({
                fieldId: 'city',
                value: address.city
            });

            subrec2.setValue({
                fieldId: 'state',
                value: state
            });

            subrec2.setValue({
                fieldId: 'zip',
                value: address.zip
            });

            /**
             * Save the record
             */
            customer.save();
        }
        catch (e) {
            this.log.debug({
                title: `addAddress error: ${e.name}`,
                details: `An error occurred while adding a new address: ${e.message}`
            });
        }
    }
```

I hope it helps...